# combining function and plotting

Tags: summation

[image]How do i merge these 3 function onto 1 set of function to plot?

Construct the series representation of a function $f(x)$ using up to $N0$ terms:

```
Sum[x^n*Subscript[c, n], {n, 0, N0}]
```

with `N0 = 5, 10, 100`:

```
f1[x_, N0_] := Sum[Subscript[c, n]x^n, {n, 1, N0}];
f1[x, 5]
f2[x_, N0_] := Sum[Subscript[c, n]x^n, {n, 1, N0}];
f2[x, 10]
f3[x_, N0_] := Sum[Subscript[c, n]x^n, {n, 1, N0}];
f3[x, 100]
```

Comment: Nabil, honestly I can't make sense of your code. Why did you define `f`, `f2`, and `f3` to have identical definitions, and then never to use them? Also, what do you mean by graphs here?

Comment: What does this have to do with *graphs*?

Comment: @MarcoB i mean the set of function. i want to plot them in one graph. im sorry i already corrected `f1` `f2` `f3` .

Comment: `Plot[{f1[x, N0], f2[x,n0], f3[x,N0]}, {x, 0, 10}]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[x_] = x^3 E^-x Sin[x];

f[n_Integer?Positive, x_] :=
 Series[f[x], {x, 0, n}] // Normal

Plot[Table[f[n, x],
   {n, {5, 10, 100}}] // Evaluate,
 {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1},
 PlotLegends -> {5, 10, 100}]
```

[image]